# Moqing UnitOfWork with lambda Expression

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, nunit, moq

I have something like this to test:

```
public void example(ModelView modelView)
        {
            //...
            var statustId= 1; 
            var requests = _unitOfWork.RequestRepository.Get(m => m.RequestStatusId == statusId);

            var requests = _unitOfWork.RequestRepository.Get(m => m.RequestTypeId == modelView.RequestTypeId);

            var oldRequests = _unitOfWork.RequestRepository.Get(m => m.Created == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7));
            //...
        }
```

How do i mock all the "GET" with different data?

This is what i got so far: not sure what the expression should look like since it is using a variables from the function.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    //Arrange
    _requestGenericRepo.Setup(m => m.Get(
      It.Is<Expression<Func<Request, bool>>>(e => e.Equals(First GET - using local variable);
    _requestGenericRepo.Setup(m => m.Get(
      It.Is<Expression<Func<Request, bool>>>(e => e.Equals(Second GET - using variable from modelView));
    _requestGenericRepo.Setup(m => m.Get(
      It.Is<Expression<Func<Request, bool>>>(e => e.Equals(Third GET));
    //Act
    var response = _controller.Example( new ModelView
    {
       RequestTypeId= 1
    }); 
    //Assert
    ...
}
```

-------------------EDIT: -------------------------------------------

It would be nice to know how to do in the above way but I can change all `Get(` To `Get().Where` like this:

```
public void example(ModelView modelView)
        {
            //...
            var statustId= 1; 
            var requests = _unitOfWork.RequestRepository.Get().Where(m => m.RequestStatusId == statusId);

            var requests = _unitOfWork.RequestRepository.Get().Where(m => m.RequestTypeId == modelView.RequestTypeId);

            var oldRequests = _unitOfWork.RequestRepository.Get().Where(m => m.Created == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7));
            //...
        }


[Test]
public void Test()
{
    //Arrange
    _requestGenericRepo.Setup(m => m.Get(
      It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Request, bool>>>());

    //Act
    var response = _controller.Example( new ModelView
    {
       RequestTypeId= 1
    }); 
    //Assert
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are each one of those expressions going to be called in the method under test in the same use case?

Comment: @Nkosi Yes... I edit my question but i would be nice to know if there is a way to get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the return value of the RequestRepository.Get method? You can try to use SetupSequence and choose path you want to test. Something like:

```
 _requestGenericRepo.SetupSequence(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Request, bool>>>())
    .Returns(/*First call*/)
    .Returns(/*Second call*/)
    .Returns(/*Third call*/);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer